Display a date from an edit form in a gallery on PowerApps
My problem is that I have a datepicker in my modification form and I would like to display the date in a gallery, here is how I did it :
in the button :
Collect(User_Pointage; { Salarié : DataCardValue1.Selected.DisplayName; Date_Pointage : DataCardValue2.SelectedDate } )
('Salarié' displays very well in the gallery)
Here is my label in my gallery :
Text(ThisItem.Date_Pointage; "dd/mm/yyyy")
with this message : This formula uses a scope, which is not currently supported for evaluation.
I tried to convert the date in the collection of my button into text and I tried lots of different formulas, I saw on a YouTube video that the configuration of my collection is correct but it does not show the configuration of his gallery
